# Difference between "matches" and "contains" in search criteria

Tags: finder, search

In my Finder search criteria, when I am filtering on a text field I have various options. One of them is "matches", and the other is "contains", but aside from establishing that they are indeed different I am unclear on what exactly either of them mean (contains `go` matches a file name `libpng.o` for example, which I also find confusing).

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have found that an easy way to decipher *exactly* what Finder means by a query is to save it as a saved search and then inspect that file with a text editor. So in your case open up Finder and make a search for `matches 'go'` and save that as a saved search, and do the same for `contains 'go'`.

If you do that, you'll see that `matches 'go'` produces this search pattern:

```
(kMDItemDisplayName = "go*"cdw)
```

whereas `contains 'go'` produces this search pattern:

```
(kMDItemDisplayName = "*go*"cd)
```

`kMDItemDisplayName` means that you're trying to match something to the displayed name of the file.

Each of the letters in `cd` and `cdw` are so called value comparison modifiers:

- The letter `c` means that the comparison is made case-insensitive (i.e. `A` and `a` are considered the same).
- The letter `d` means that the comparison is insensitive to diacritical marks (i.e.`è` and `e` are considered the same).
- The letter `w` means that the comparison is word-based, and that the comparison detects transitions from lower-case to upper-case.

You can find the documentation of the value comparison modifiers in [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corespotlight/cssearchquery#1965652).

So in your scenario `matches 'go'` means that it will search for files where the name has a word inside it that starts with the string `go` (i.e. there could be any suffix to the string in the word) - ignoring case and various marks.

Similarly, `contains 'go'` means that it will search for files where the name has the string `go` somewhere inside it (i.e. there could any prefix or suffix to the string) - ignoring case and various marks.

Comment: Interesting, from testing it appears that MacOS thinks the period in `libpng.o` is a diacritical mark.

Comment: Yes, it is simply disregarded in the matching - so "g.o" matches "*go*" (star g o star) in this particular case.

Comment: There is an additional twist for multi-word searches: Spotlight treats _contains_ `go fish` as looking for the specific string entered (with the space), but _matches_ `go fish` is treated as (_matches_ `go` AND _matches_ `fish`).

Answer (score -2):

matches is the `exact` meaning, so if only one char (even hidden ones) is invisible, it will not match.

contains is more flexible, and will `match` also substrings

Comment: This is wildly imprecise, `matches` isn't an 'exact match', e.g. `go` will match `goals`, `myGoals` but not `mygoals`.